# Javascript Скрыть элемент при data == true

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция, как правильно написать, что бы при data == true элемент скрывался

```js
$('.btn_buy, .service-buy').on('click', function() {
  var additional_id = $(this).val();
  var url = document.URL.split('/');

  if (url[3] == 'ru-ru') {
    var tabUrl = "/ru-ru/site/add-additional-to-basket";
  } else {
    var tabUrl = "/site/add-additional-to-basket";
  }
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      additional_id: additional_id
    },
    url: tabUrl,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == true) {
        //ПИСАТЬ ТУТ


      }
    },
    error: function() {

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="service-link" href="/ru-ru/site/service?id=3">Регистрация VAT</a></td>
    <td class="td-prise">222.00<button type="button" id="add_to_basket_buy" class="btn btn_buy" value="3">Buy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="service-link" href="/ru-ru/site/service?id=4">Регистрация в налоговых органах</a></td>
    <td class="td-prise">345.00<button type="button" id="add_to_basket_buy" class="btn btn_buy" value="4">Buy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="service-link" href="/ru-ru/site/service?id=10">sdf</a></td>
    <td class="td-prise">333.00<button type="button" id="add_to_basket_buy" class="btn btn_buy" value="10">Buy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="service-link" href="/ru-ru/site/service?id=156">zaaaa</a></td>
    <td class="td-prise">95.00<button type="button" id="add_to_basket_buy" class="btn btn_buy" value="156">Buy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="service-link" href="/ru-ru/site/service?id=157">expire_add</a></td>
    <td class="td-prise">95.00<button type="button" id="add_to_basket_buy" class="btn btn_buy" value="157">Buy</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="service-link" href="/ru-ru/site/service?id=158">sdfsdf</a></td>
    <td class="td-prise">234.00<button type="button" id="add_to_basket_buy" class="btn btn_buy" value="158">Buy</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: какой именно элемент?

Comment: <button type="button" id="add_to_basket_buy" class="btn btn_buy" value="3">Buy</button>

Comment: Но кнопок много и нужно что бы скрылась именно эта кнопка. В additional_id приходит id этого элемента

Comment: в таком виде `var additional_id = $(this).val();` в additional_id Никакого id Не будет

Comment: При console.log(additional_id); показываеь id этого элемента

Comment: Всего элемента, не кнопки.

Comment: добавь в сниппет разметку html к которой твой скрипт применяется, чтобы было видно что конкретно ты хочешь убрать

Comment: Добавил часть таблицы

Comment: ага, и что из этой разметки должно убраться при клике на кнопку buy?

Comment: Допустим при клике на первый buy мне нужно что бы скрылась или сама кнопка, или вся tr

Comment: почему у всех кнопок одинаковый айди? document.getElementById("some-id").style.visibility = 'hidden';

Comment: Там сложная логика на бекенде, я туда не лезу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запомните кнопку в переменную, например, `button` и скрывайте именно ее

```js
$('.btn_buy, .service-buy').on('click', function() {
  var button = $(this);
  var additional_id = button.val();
  var url = document.URL.split('/');

  if (url[3] == 'ru-ru') {
    var tabUrl = "/ru-ru/site/add-additional-to-basket";
  } else {
    var tabUrl = "/site/add-additional-to-basket";
  }
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      additional_id: additional_id
    },
    url: tabUrl,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == true) {
        button.hide();
      }
    },
    error: function() {

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)))